# Infinitely many nonempty Seiberg-Witten moduli spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, moduli-spaces, spin-geometry, gauge-theory

The classic "finiteness" statement in Seiberg-Witten (SW) theory is that, for any smooth closed connected 4-manifold, there are only finitely many spin-c structures with nontrivial SW invariants. The literature typically goes further to claim that there are only finitely many spin-c structures with nonempty SW moduli spaces, but we need to be careful with the statement:

**Is there a 4-manifold $X$ with $b^2_+(X)>1$, and a** "non-generic" **pair of Riemannian metric $g$ and closed self-dual 2-form perturbation $\mu$ on $X$, for which there are** *infinitely* **many nonempty (perturbed) irreducible SW moduli spaces (indexed over the set of spin-c structures)?**

Fix a pair $(g,\mu)$. For each spin-c structure $\mathfrak s$ the Weitzenbock formula and SW equations yield a uniform upper bound on the SW spinors (independent of $\mathfrak s$), hence on the self-dual part of the SW curvatures (using the SW curvature equation), hence on $c_1(\mathfrak s)^2=\frac{1}{4\pi^2}\int_X(|F_A^+|^2- |F_A^-|^2)\text{dvol}_g$ via Chern-Weil theory. *When the pair is chosen generically,* there are no SW solutions whenever its "virtual dimension" is negative, yielding a uniform lower bound on $c_1(\mathfrak s)^2$ in terms of the topology of the 4-manifold, $c_1(\mathfrak s)^2\ge2\chi(X)+3\sigma(X)$. This is enough to 'bound' $c_1(\mathfrak s)$ in $H^2(X;\mathbb Z)$ and get the desired finiteness statement (even in the presence of reducible SW solutions).

LeBrun pointed out a trick if we allow *reducible* unperturbed SW solutions (i.e. ASD connections with vanishing spinors). Take $\mu=0$ and any $(X,g)$ with $\text{Tors} H^2(X;\mathbb Z)=0$ that has a spin-c structure with connection $(\mathbb S_+,\nabla)$ whose determinant bundle is nontrivial with a $g$-ASD connection $(\det(\mathbb S_+),\nabla^t)$. Then the induced spin-c structure $\mathbb S_+^k:=\mathbb S_+\otimes\det(\mathbb S_+)^{\otimes k}$ for any $k\in\mathbb Z$ has $g$-ASD connection $(2k+1)\nabla^t$ on $\det(\mathbb S_+^k)=\det(\mathbb S_+)^{\otimes(2k+1)}$. For example, there are flat 4-tori with such Hermitian bundles.

[Aside: When $b^2_+(X)=1$, we learn that each perturbation can only lie in finitely many chambers with nontrivial SW invariants.]